# Truncate URL's with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, wordpress

I am trying to strip incoming page requests to 25 characters after the year/month structure of the URL on my Wordpress server. Reason is, there are a number of external 404 links that I would like to resolve. The Wordpress server is able to guess what the page should be. So far, I have the following Rewrite Rules configured:

```
RewriteRule     "/\d{4}/\d{2}/.{25}\.html$" - [L]
RewriteRule     "/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(.{25}).+\.html$" "/$1/$2/$3.html" [L]
```

I have these rules set in sites-available/site-name.

The rewrite log shows the URL as being re-written, however the link still results in a 404 and the rewritten URL is not passed to the browser.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think you want to change `.{25}` to `.{,25}` as the former will only match 25 characters (ie. if only 24 characters were present, it would not match)

Comment: I would also suggest that you want to 301 redirect such requests. This will let search engines update their indices.

Comment: I have made the following rule changes with still no luck.

`RewriteRule     /[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/.{1,25}\.html$ - [L]`


`RewriteRule     ^/([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/(.{25}).*\.html$ /$1/$2/$3.html [R=302,L]`